# HTML tags not being rendered

Tags: php, html, fuelphp

I'm building a simple blog system with FuelPHP and TinyMCE editor.

When I format my text in the TinyMCE (or CKEditor, doesn't matter) and save it in my database everything is OK. However when I print the text back, surprisingly, my browser won't render the html tags and displays them as plain text!

I have checked and I don't have any kind of `CDATA` in the page, that might cause the issue.

Here is how it renders:

[image: How it renders]

However, when inspecting the issue with FireBug, I noticed a lot of spaces before the `<h2>` tag is being printed! If I just make a small change in the spaces (Remove one or add another), then the browser will render the tags and display the text properly!!

Can you guys help me with this issue? It's really weird.

Comment: How can you pass the data to the view? Can you show the code? If you are using the View class there is a method which can let you choice when to encode the text or not (default is yes): http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/view.html#/method_set

Comment: @MarcoPace Oh yea.. You made my day Marco :) Thanks very much. I had just ignored that parameter :p

Comment: Very good :-), I'll write and answer for future purpose

Comment: FuelPHP encodes on output as a security measure. Every variable send to a view will be encoded, unless you explicitly disable it, either via set() or set_safe().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you save your data in database its encoded for some security reasons you just need to

`html_entity_decode("string retrived from database");`

and then print it.

Comment: I've checked the database. and it is stored as plain text with http tags.

Comment: That was not the issue. However FuelPHP did the encoding after it retrieved the text from the database. Using the function helped solving the issue. Thx

Comment: @MiroMarkaravanes How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of encoding and decoding you can use the [`set_safe()` method](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/view.html#/method_set_safe) or use the `$filter` argument in [`set()`](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/view.html#/method_set).

Like this:

```
$view->set_safe('body', $data);
```

Or

```
$view->set('body', $data, false);
```

Or whitelist your view. Which will prevent decoding.

Answer (score 0):

How can you pass the data to the view? Can you show the code?

If you are using the [View class there is a method](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/view.html#/method_set) which can let you choice when to encode the text or not (default is **yes**).