# Laravel CKEditor Saves to DB but HTML does not render on page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have CKEditor enabled for `details` in my view for Projects.  All is working fine as in I can create a new project and it saves to the database.  When I look in the projects table in the `details` column I see my html `<p>This is some details</p>`.  When I try showing the `$project->details` in a view it does not render the HTML and just prints to `<p>This is some details</p>` the screen.

[As this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292609/html-tags-not-being-rendered) From my blade file I tried `{{ html_entity_decode($project->details) }}` and it does the same thing (doesnt render html from database).  I believe this is specific to Laravel and how it fetches/stores the data because I previously had this project in Codeigniter and was able to simply echo the value to the screen.

**When I use** `{{ html_entity_decode($project->details) }}`**I Get this:**
[image: with html entity decode]

This will render the HTML but I don't think it is how I should be doing it and it prints a number (in this case 1) after the HTML.
`{{ print($project->details) }}`

**This is what happens when I use (notice the random 1 at the bottom)** `{{ $project->details }}` 
[image: using print]

**Here is my DB table**
[image: database table]

How do I get the html to render on the page/is print the best way to do this in laravel or php?

Comment: It'd be easier for others to understand exact problem by printing the exact result.

Comment: When I use `{{ html_entity_decode($project->details) }}` in my view it prints `<p>This is some details</p>`.  When I use `{{ print($project->details) }}` it prints `This is some details 1`.  In my `projects` table in the `details` column I see `<p>This is some details</p>`.  I will try to add some screenshots to see if it makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why that '1' should show up. Can you make sure you don't have any Mutators on your model.

Also if you are pretty sure about all the data coming from your DB and want to output the html as is you can try `{!! $project->details !!}`

Comment: `{!! $project->details !!}` did the trick.  Can you tell me what the difference is in using `{{ $project->details }}` and `{!! $project->details !!}`?

Comment: Outputting variables using: {{ $variableName }}  executes an escape string method before actually displaying the variable's value to avoid [XSS Attacks](https://excess-xss.com) and injecting any sort of script into your page especially if the value of that variable was set from a public facing input. Using {!! !!} is like telling blade not to escape any sorts of scripts (including html tags) and should be only used if you're sure 100% that the value of your variable doesn't have any maleficent script.