# Include file in textarea and make style of text

Tags: html

I have a `textarea` in which I including outside .php file which contain text.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="terms" value="" disabled><?php include 'outsidefile.php'; ?></textarea>
```

The text is appear on textarea perfectly. The file content is

```
<?php
     echo 'Some text';
?>
```

Now i want to make style for this `Some text` for example

```
<?php
     echo '<p style="font-size: 46px;text-align: center;">Some text</p>';
?>
```

But when I load the page I see exactly this `<p style="font-size: 46px;text-align: center;">Some text</p>` instead of text with size 46px and centered.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292609/html-tags-not-being-rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add HTML to textarea values. They are simply an input type, and anything between the `<textarea>` tags are considered a string, and not parsed as HTML. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea) for making a div editable.

Comment: Oh, didn't knew this. But can I disable this editable div? I want to render text without to be editable?

Comment: Don't include it within a `<textarea>`? A `<textarea>` is an editable field, if you don't want them to edit it, why include it in there?

Comment: Oh, yes. I saw that is possible. Because I didn't knew that this is possible with this

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `HTML` element or it's style into `textarea`.

Use `contenteditable` `div` insted of `textarea`.

See Example,

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #likeInput {
        -webkit-appearance: textfield;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
        user-select: text;
        cursor: auto;
        padding: 1px;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: inset;
        border-color: initial;
        border-image: initial;
        text-rendering: auto;
        color: initial;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-spacing: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        text-indent: 0px;
        text-shadow: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: start;
        margin: 0em;
        font: 13.3333px Arial;
        border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
        -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="likeInput" disabled="disabled"><?php include 'outsidefile.php'; ?></div>
```